# Monogame run causes display drivers to crash

Tags: c#, crash, pixel, monogame

I have come across an error I have never seen before and was hoping someone could help me out.

I'm making a game and I re-colour individual pixels on a collision. Today I got that working on my laptop with no errors whatsoever.

However, when working on the same project on my desktop PC, there are a few issues:

1. The monitor flickers off for around a second and comes back on, with a system try icon warning saying that the display driver has crashed and has recovered.
2. The game crashes with a vshst32.exe error which the debugger doesn't pick up.

I have found the chunk of code that causes the issue, if I take it out the game runs fine:

```
foreach (Projectiles rocket in rockets)
        {
            if (myObstacle.collisionBox.Intersects(rocket.collisionBox))
            {
                if (rocket.position.X >= myObstacle.position.X)
                {
                    int x = random.Next(0, myObstacle.texture.Width);
                    int y = random.Next(0, myObstacle.texture.Height);
                    int oWidth = random.Next(30, 90);
                    int oHeight = random.Next(30, 90);

                    Rectangle pixelRegion = new Rectangle(x, y, oWidth, oHeight);

                    Color[] pixelData = new Color[oWidth * oHeight];

                    myObstacle.texture.GetData<Color>(0, pixelRegion, pixelData, 0, oWidth * oHeight);

                    for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Color backgroundColor = new Color(114, 176, 244);
                        pixelData[i] = backgroundColor*0.001f;
                    }
                    myObstacle.texture.SetData<Color>(0, pixelRegion, pixelData, 0, oWidth * oHeight);

                    rocket.visible = false;
                    particleEngineRocket.emitterLocation.X = offScreen;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `myObstacle.texture.SetData` line?

Comment: By the way, `SetData` is a relatively expensive call to be calling every frame

Comment: If I comment out SetData, the game runs, but nothing happens in regard to recolouring my texture :)